# How to filter Rows in a Data Table using IBindingListView

Tags: c#, datatable

I am having a data table with some rows and columns. I want to filter the rows based on the string typed in the filter. 
The idea is the filter (string) looks for the matches in the column [0] of the table and show the filtered rows.
Here is the code I am using: (But it didn't work). Here, Column[0] name is Tags.

```
    private void txtbFilterTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
        string filter = t.Text;
        IBindingListView blv = MainWindow.m_DtTagList.DefaultView;



        if (filter == "")
        { 
            blv.Filter = null; 
        }

        else
        {
            try
            {


                blv.Filter = "Tags '" + filter;
            }
            catch
            {


            }
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following

```
blv.Filter = "Tags LIKE '%" + filter + "%'";
```